# Ruby add 31 days to date string within 2d array

Tags: ruby, arrays, string, date

I have a 2d array.

```
 array = [["2014-01-12", "2014-01-12", "2014-01-12"],
          ["2012-08-26", "2012-10-18", "2012-08-31"],
          ["2013-04-09", "2013-05-22", "2013-07-01"]]
```

I need to add 31 days to the third value in each sub array (eg: "2014-01-12" & "2012-08-31" & "2012-07-01")

I have considered something like:

```
changed_date = array.map { |due| ((Date.strptime(due[2], "%Y-%m-%d"))+ 31) }
```

But wanted to see what other ways there are of doing this...

Thanks!

EDIT:

I need the result to be an array of strings with with row.last having an additional 31 days. The resulting array should look like this:

```
array = ["2014-02-12", "2012-09-31", "2012-08-31"]
```

Comment: I am Ok your approach!

Comment: What do you mean by eg: "2014-01-12" & "2012-08-31" & "2012-08-31"? What does that refer to?

Comment: In view of @konsolebox's answer and your comment on it, your expression for `changed_date` was misleading, as it indicated you wanted an array of arrays of date objects, not date strings.  That could have been avoided if you had included "desired results" in your answer; i.e., `changed_date => [["2014-01-12", "2014-02-12", "2014-01-12"],...]`.  When you give an example (which is highly desirable), it's always best to give both the results you got and what you wanted.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! There can be such a volume of stuff to learn when you're starting out, evening knowing how to ask a good question is an ongoing learning process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing it correct but you're changing your array form. Perhaps you should do

```
array.map{ |due| due[2] = (Date.strptime(due[2]) + 31).strftime("%Y-%m-%d"); due }
```

Or

```
array.each{ |due| due[2] = (Date.strptime(due[2]) + 31).strftime("%Y-%m-%d"); }
```

Comment: Thanks, you got to the heart of the problem I was having, without my realising that it was the form of the data that I was changing that was causing my issues in some environments.

Comment: Good mind-meld. It should be noted that both of these modify `array`.

Answer (score 2):

As you asked, thus I am writing.. But your way is perfect.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'date'

array = [["2014-01-12", "2014-01-12", "2014-01-12"],
         ["2012-08-26", "2012-10-18", "2012-08-31"],
         ["2013-04-09", "2013-05-22", "2013-07-01"]]

p array.map { |a| Date.parse(a[2]).next_day(31) }
# => [#<Date: 2014-02-12 ((2456701j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>,
# #<Date: 2012-10-01 ((2456202j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>, 
# #<Date: 2013-08-01 ((2456506j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>]
```

[next_day([n=1]) → date](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-next_day) says

> This method is equivalent to d + n.

Comment: @BorisStitnicky Happy to see you.. I am reading, what you said. Lots of hope.

Comment: I just replied, check your email.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that you wrote `changed_date = array.map..` and evidently wanted `changed_map` to be an array of arrays of strings, it appears you want the method to be non-destructive; that is, to leave `array` unchanged.  If that's the case, @konsolebox's answer needs to be modified slightly:

```
array.map{ |row|
        row[0..-2] << (Date.strptime(row.last) + 31).strftime("%Y-%m-%d") }
  #=> [["2014-01-12", "2014-01-12", "2014-02-12"],
  #    ["2012-08-26", "2012-10-18", "2012-10-01"],
  #    ["2013-04-09", "2013-05-22", "2013-08-01"]]
array
  #=> [["2014-01-12", "2014-01-12", "2014-01-12"],
  #    ["2012-08-26", "2012-10-18", "2012-08-31"],
  #    ["2013-04-09", "2013-05-22", "2013-07-01"]]
```

Alternatively,

```
t = array.transpose
  #=> [["2014-01-12", "2012-08-26", "2013-04-09"],
  #    ["2014-01-12", "2012-10-18", "2013-05-22"],
  #    ["2014-01-12", "2012-08-31", "2013-07-01"]]

(t[0..-2] << t.last.map { |d| (Date.strptime(d) + 31).strftime("%Y-%m-%d") })
  .transpose
  #=> [["2014-01-12", "2014-01-12", "2014-02-12"],
  #    ["2012-08-26", "2012-10-18", "2012-10-01"],
  #    ["2013-04-09", "2013-05-22", "2013-08-01"]]
```